# Diagnose Avaya IP Config to SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, telephone

We have 10 phone extensions that instead of gettings messages on the phone, we configured the Avaya IP Office to forward messages to a specific email for each extension.  The SMTP server adress is specified in avaya settings and a local Windows server IIS 6.0 SMTP service.  This has been working well for years.

Since yesterday the emails are no longer being sent.  I rebooted the Avaya system a few time, and everytime the emails work for the 5-10 first minutes.  I am in the dark here.  How do I diagnostic this problem, I am not sure what I am looking for?

- I rebooted the Avaya Switch at least 4 times, same results
- I rebooted my DC/DNS/SMTP server
- I tried to look at SMTP logs, Firewall logs, Event logs
- I am able to ping the avaya switch, it's on the same subnet
- The SMTP seems to work, whenever I put a file in my SMTP C:\inetpub\mailroot\Pickup it is sent right away.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Run a packet capture on the SMTP server and initiate a message from the Avaya. Then inspect the capture. That may give you a clue as to what's happening. If the email is hitting the server you can rule out the Avaya and the network. If it isn't hitting the SMTP server you can rule out the SMTP server. Troubleshoot further based on your capture results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the communication between the phone switch and the SMTP server was interrupted because of an IP adress conflict.  A second internet line and modem was added a few weeks ago but not configured correctly, so its DHCP started to generate conflicting IPs.  That explains why the system could work for a few minutes after a reboot, it was until the configuration spread to the network.

Since I could not find the option to deactivate the DHCP on the new modem, I unplugged it until I have the time to configure it correctly.  Everything is back to normal.